# calling rails helper method inside javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I need to call a rails helper method and get the values as array so that javascript can process it. Is it possible to call rails helper inside javascript. I am trying to integrate jquerys autocomplete feature in my application. Please find the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //**Here the rails helper method will get the list of items**    

   function split(val) {
       return val.split(/,\s*/);
   }

   function extractLast(term) {
       return split(term).pop();
   }

   $("#tags")
   // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
   .bind("keyup", function (event) {
       if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
           event.preventDefault();
       }
   }).autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: function (request, response) {
           // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
           response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
           availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
       },
       focus: function () {
           // prevent value inserted on focus
           return false;
       },
       select: function (event, ui) {
           var terms = split(this.value);
           // remove the current input
           terms.pop();
           // add the selected item
           terms.push(ui.item.value);
           // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
           terms.push("");
           this.value = terms.join(", ");
           return false;
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: I dont know much of javascript. But u can use this gem to get all your ruby variables in javascript https://github.com/gazay/gon

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to use your Rails helpers in your JavaScript files.

You can however make this list/array available to your JS by placing them inside script tags in your markup, or add them as [data-attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) that could be later fetched by JavaScript. Another solution would be to use the [Gon](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript) gem as commented.